# Is there a way to pass an argument that will be defined within the function to a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, undefined

I want to pass an argument into a function, without it being defined at the time I pass it in. It will then be defined within the function, and I can pass it as an argument to another function. I can't define the argument I want to pass in before hand, as it is reliant on a loop within the first function. The real situation I'm using it for is a bit more complicated, but I think this example sums it up.

I tried this:

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a + b

def fun2(f, *args):
    total = 0
    for c in range(5):
        total += f(*args)
        
    return total

fun2(fun1, 1, c)
```

but that returns the error

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Perhaps you wanted to return a value? `c = fun2(fun1, 1)`

Comment: Variables are defined in their function scopes, but I don't understand the need for this. You can simply do `total += f(args[0], c)` (or `total += f(*(args + (c,)))` if it must support a dynamic number of arguments) and then call it using `fun2(fun1, 1)`.

Comment: Maybe the example is a little _too_ minimal. What's the expected output?  15?  I don't quite understand the need to pass in c at all, why can't it just be local inside f2.

Comment: I think in this case you're better off posting your actual code, not a dummy example. This comes across like an xy-question because it's not clear why you think you need to do it this way.